# factor analysis of mixed data - difference between quality and contribution

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I started to use the R package [FactoMineR](https://rdrr.io/cran/FactoMineR/) to perform factor analysis of mixed data (function FAMD).

Could someone please be so kind and explain the difference between quality (cos2) and contribution (contrib)?